# "activeStyle" attribute always applying on links to pages\index.js

Tags: html, reactjs, gatsby

I'm pretty new to Gatsby/React and web development in general, so this may be a very simple fix, but I can't figure out what the problem could be.

I'm currently working on my header and making links to each of the pages on my website and am having some trouble with the "activeStyle" attribute. So before describing specifics here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
<Link to="/" activeStyle={{color: 'gold'}}>Home</Link>
```

When I place this link on a page other than home it will still highlight the link gold even though it isn't actually the active page. However, if I use the same exact code but instead link to the /about page, it will work correctly and the link will only be gold if I am on the about page. Am I missing something?

I attempted to set the link to="/index", but Gatsby through an error at me saying that "/index" does not exist and gave a list of the pages on my site, one of which was "/". I honestly can't think of what's going on with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Link` doesnt have `activeStyle` prop. Instead of using `Link` you should use `NavLink`. It has the following props:

```
<NavLink>
  activeClassName: string
  activeStyle: object // seems you are looking for this one
  exact: bool
  strict: bool
  isActive: func
  location: object
```

[`react-router v4`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web) doc might be useful for you

Comment: Link is a component specific to Gatsby, I believe. After reading through the Gatsby docs some more I realized that setting exact to true in the Link component forces Gatsby to use React's original NavLink component, and then activeStyle worked. Thanks for steering me in the right direction!